# HTML Onmouseover Help Changing Image

Tags: html, onmouseover

I need help changing this image when it is moused over. This does not work. Please help?

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('gotosite').

        src='b.png';"

        onmouseout="document.getElementById('myimage1'src='bmo.png';">   

        <img src="b.png" id="gotosite" /></a>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('myimage1'src='bmo.png';`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<img src="image.png" onmouseover="this.src='image.png'" onmouseout="this.src='image.png'" width="70" height="70" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code. First, in your `onmouseout` code you have the wrong ID for the image. It should be `gotosite` but you you have `myimage1`. Also, you're missing some parentheses and a period following `document.getElementById('myimage1'`.

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('gotosite').src='b.png';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('gotosite').src='bmo.png';"><img src="b.png" id="gotosite" /></a>
```

Here is a fiddle using this code with only the image URLs changed:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwnace/w2cL69x3/